# is update with left join will lock all MyIsam tables mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, atomic

I am doing a table update in mysql including 2 left join on other tables. This is all MyIsam tables.

> UPDATE `DB`.`tutorial_code` LEFT JOIN `tutorial` ON `tutorial`.`id_tutorial`=`tutorial_code`.`ref_tutorial` LEFT JOIN `tutorial_code_language` ON `tutorial_code_language`.`id_tutorial_code_language`='1' SET `tutorial_code` = 'code to be added',`ref_tutorial_code_language` = '2' WHERE `tutorial_code`.`id_tutorial_code` ='3' AND `tutorial`.`ref_tutorial_main`='1' AND `tutorial_code_language`.`id_tutorial_code_language`='1'

I am wondering if only the table updated will be locked during the process or if the total of the 3 tables (the update one and the two joined ones) will be locked during the process. Indeed I don't want the joined tables to be modified during the process as the update depends on them.

If the 2 joined tables are not locked, I guess that I will have to use lock and lock write every tables used

Answer (score 1):

They will all lock.

Comment: thank you very much PMV. but can you give me information that prove it (mysql documentation, performed test...).

Comment: ALL writes operations lock ALL the used MyISAM tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-locking.html , switch to InnoDB :)